# How to make html elements created by javascript to appear at the top of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written a JavaScript file which is included in the head of the HTML code. This JavaScript code creates some new `div` and `iframe` on the webpage. Javascript creates these division after 10 minutes . this notification is forsession time out.

But I already have a division which loads oracle forms inside it. I want to keep this forms `div` in the bottom of page.

Is it possible to move this forms `div` downwards automatically when the new `div` appears (which are created by the JavaScript code). Nothing should overlap.

I want to keep `div` (created by JavaScript) on the top, because that contains a notification .

Below is the code I have written :

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Kshitij Jain</title>
    <script src="../common/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#menu").html('<object data="http://209.34.231.132/forms/frmservlet?form=ClmRepymt&amp;config=common">');
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var logoutPath = '<%=ServerSupportUtil.getURL(response,ServerSupportUtil.getApplURL()+"/servlets/MenuServlet?dirc=logout")%>';
        var sessionTimeout = '<%=session.getMaxInactiveInterval()%>';
        var refreshSessionUrl = '<%=ServerSupportUtil.getApplURL()%>/common/refreshsession.jsp';
        var countDownSeconds = '<%=CommonSupportUtil.getSessionTimeoutCountDownSec()%>';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ServerSupportUtil.getApplURL() %>/common/net.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ServerSupportUtil.getApplURL() %>/common/AjaxSessionTimer.js"></script>
    <style>
        object {
            width:825px; 
            height:625px;
            z-index: -100;
        }
    </style>
</head>   

<div id="menu"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, the `div` having `id='menu'` contains oracle forms. Notification should appear above this `div`.

I cannot change my JavaScript code as it is generic for whole web application. All changes should be inside this JSP.

Comment: You're missing your opening <body> tag. I'm not completely sure I understand you, but you could use $('body').prepend('<div />') to add a div to the very top of your page, otherwise you can use jQuery's after() method to inject content after some other specific element.

Comment: a new div is created by ajaxSessionTimer.js. I want to appear that div at top of the page without changing the ajaxSessionTimer.js.

Comment: @ChrisHardie The opening and closing `body` and `html` tags are optional.

Comment: Sorry I missed to put body here. I added it here.

Comment: Use `$("YourDivHere").insertBefore($("body"));`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your other js file which you haven't shown us is adding the content via `appendTo('body')` or similar. In which case, you can move this part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#menu").html('<object data="http://209.34.231.132/forms/frmservlet?form=ClmRepymt&amp;config=common">');
});
```

Below the script that loads the other content, and change it to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#menu").html('<object data="http://209.34.231.132/forms/frmservlet?form=ClmRepymt&amp;config=common">').appendTo('body');
});
```

Which should move the `#menu` div to the end of the page.

Comment: Your solution will not work here, because javascript create notification division after whole page is loaded, and that also after 10 minutes. THis notification is for session time out .

Comment: In that case, use absolute positioning to make the notification div float on top of the page.